# Show DFP ad link in in app browser

Tags: ios, ads, google-dfp

I have integrated DFPBannerView in my application.
When the banner ad is clicked, it jumps out of the application and opens the related link in Safari.
I want to change this behaviour. So, when a user clicks on the banner the link should open inside the application in a webview. I am not able to find any delegate method or property by which I can get the link or the method which gets triggered.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are already using the "new" GPT-tags in your mobile application. My first approach would be as easy as changing the "_blank"-option to "_top"-option. For general easier usage you can also change the default in the admin/network-panel inside the DFP UI. 
If this for some reason doesn't fix the issue, a look into your implementation would be very helpful.
Usually you can just go to the Ad Unit inside the DFP UI and 'generate the tags' and it should work correct, in case you didn't know.